# What is the best practise to extract a pattern from a string en C# and use it to create variables

Tags: c#, regex, string, substring

Let's consider a string like this :

```
string myString = "C125:AAAAA|C12:22222|C16542:D1|ABCD:1234A|C6:12AAA"
```

I'd like to end with something like that :

```
string C125 = "AAAAA";
string C12 = "22222";
string C16542 = "D1";
string C6 = "12AAA";
```

It means that I'd like to extract substrings (or whatever) that matches the pattern "C+characters:characters" (and exclude other patterns like `ABCD:1234A` e.g.). Then automatically create a variable that would have the 1st part of my "substring" (`"C125:AAAAA"` e.g.) as a name (so string `C125` in that case) and the 2nd part of my substring as a value (`"AAAAA"` e.g.).

What would be the best practise to do that in C# ? Thx !

Comment: Essentially, you don't. You can make a list or dictionary of strings perhaps but it depends on how you are using it

Comment: Unless you are dealing with meta-programming / code generation, you cannot do that. You *can* generate the desired *source code* as another multi-line string, but you cannot generate additional *variables* at run-time.

Comment: You could hack it by converting your data to JSON, then reading said JSON in a dynamic object. I'd still go with Dictionary, however.

Answer (score 3):

use a dictionary to store your values:

```
string myString = "C125:AAAAA|C12:22222|C16542:D1|ABCD:1234A|C6:12AAA";
Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
myString.Split('|').ToList().ForEach(x => result.Add(x.Split(':')[0], x.Split(':')[1]));
```

**Update** - improved solution from CodesInChaos:

```
string myString = "C125:AAAAA|C12:22222|C16542:D1|ABCD:1234A|C6:12AAA";
Dictionary<string, string> result = myString.Split('|').Select(x => x.Split(':')).ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);
```

Comment: I'd prefer `Dictionary<string, string> result = myString.Split('|').Select(x => x.Split(':')).ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1])`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex, that will match any combination of word characters with length 1 or more that came after `:` .

```
@":(\w+)"
```

*Note* that the preceding pattern used capture grouping so for get the proper result you need to print the 1st group.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mF2uP2/1)

or you can use a positive look behind :

```
@"(?<=:)\w+"
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mF2uP2/2)

But if you want to create a name from first part the better choice for such tasks is use a data structure like `dictionary`.

So you can loop over the result if following command :

```
Match match = Regex.Match(text, (\w+):(\w+));
```

And put the pairs of 1st and 2nd groups within a dictionary.

Comment: "Then automatically create a variable that would have the 1st part of my "substring" as a name and the 2nd part of my substring as a value"

Comment: @AvinashRaj I do that ;)

Answer (score 1):

if your purpose is code-generation, you can create a StringBuilder:

```
string myString = "C125:AAAAA|C12:22222|C16542:D1|ABCD:1234A|C6:12AAA";

var res = myString.Split('|')
                  .Select(s=>s.Split(':'))
                  .Where(arr=>arr[0][0] == 'C')
                  .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), 
                            (b, t)=>b.AppendFormat("string {0} = \"{1}\";", t[0], t[1])
                                     .AppendLine());
```

output:

```
string C125 = "AAAAA";
string C12 = "22222";
string C16542 = "D1";
string C6 = "12AAA";
```

if your purpose to store values with keys, you can create a Dictionary

```
string myString = "C125:AAAAA|C12:22222|C16542:D1|ABCD:1234A|C6:12AAA";

var D = myString.Split('|')
                .Select(s=>s.Split(':'))
                .Where(arr=>arr[0][0] == 'C')
                .ToDictionary(arr=>arr[0], arr=>arr[1]);
```

output:

```
[C125, AAAAA]
[C12, 22222]
[C16542, D1]
[C6, 12AAA]
```

format of input string is not complex, so String.Split would more appropriate here, than RegEx

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps, you could use something like this.You could simply use the string split.

```
 string myString = "C125:AAAAA|C12:22222|C16542:D1|ABCD:1234A|C6:12AAA";
        StringBuilder result=new StringBuilder();
        List<string> resulttemp = myString.Split('|').ToList();
        foreach (string[] temp in from v in resulttemp where v.StartsWith("C") select v.Split(':'))
        {
            result.Append("string ");
            result.Append(temp[0]);
            result.Append("=");
            result.Append("\"");
            result.Append(temp[1]);
            result.Append("\"");
            result.Append(";");
            result.Append("\n");
        }
```